# How to prove $\frac{ab^2}{1+2b^2+c^2}+\frac{bc^2}{1+2c^2+a^2}+\frac{ca^2}{1+2a^2+b^2} \le \frac{3}{4}$ if $a+b+c=3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, summation, alternative-proof, buffalo-way

$a,b,c\ge 0,a+b+c=3.$ Prove:
$$\frac{ab^2}{1+2b^2+c^2}+\frac{bc^2}{1+2c^2+a^2}+\frac{ca^2}{1+2a^2+b^2} \le \frac{3}{4}$$

This  problem was found in this [post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1548159p9400204). As you can see, no one in that post gave a correct proof but someone pointed out that this inequality might be a problem from [Mathematical Reflections](https://www.awesomemath.org/mathematical-reflections/). However, the archive of the journal can't be downloaded. Therefore, we must find our own solution.

I tried it myself surely. And because all variables show up in a single fraction, we are hard to use technique like tangent line. I tried to homogenise it, and it turned out to be
[image: What a monster,isn't it]
(in case you didn't understand, this triangle denotes the coefficients of ever term of the polynomial. From the left-top is coefficient of $a^7$, and right-top is that of $b^7$, and the bottom is that of $c^7$. And for instance, the "$762$" on the second term of the second line denotes the coefficient of $a^5bc$)
which is almost impossilbe to create a proof directly from it by hand.(Sure, since expanding is not always a perfect way)

Can you come up with a solution with wit?

Comment: It's obviously true by BW.

Comment: BW? Michael Rozenberg, could you please elaborate your argument?

Comment: @RAHUL About BW see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h514567

Comment: @Michel Rozenberg.- For many people (I included) this problem is difficult. Can you be so kind to say what does mean BW without the reference you gave to RAHUL? I believe in your "obviously true by BW" but for me it does'nt at all. For this I don't spent time to try find a solution. Thanks you. (Sorry for English)

Comment: @Piquito
  I gave a wrong link. Sorry. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h522084 See now.

Comment: @Michel Rozenberg.- Thanks you very much. Greetings.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg.- So BW (Buffalo Way) is as efficient in math as Buffalo Bill was in life, in war, and in economics. Thank you very much Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab^2}{1+2b^2+c^2}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab^2}{b^2+c^2+2b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{3ab^2}{5b^2+3c^2+2ab+2bc}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{3ab^2}{5b^2+3c^2+2ab+2bc}\leq\frac{3}{4}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{3ab^2}{5b^2+3c^2+2ab+2bc}\leq\frac{a+b+c}{12}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(30a^6b-63a^5b^2+45a^5c^2+63a^4b^3-15a^4c^3+20a^5bc-103a^4b^2c+95a^4c^2b+108a^3b^3c-180a^3b^2c^2)\geq0.$$
Now, since $$\sum_{cyc}(26a^6b-63a^5b^2+2a^5c^2+50a^4b^3-15a^4c^3)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}a^2b(26a^4-63a^3b+50a^2b^2-15ab^3+2b^4)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}a^2b(a-b)^2(26a^2-11ab+2b^2)\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove that:$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^6b+43a^5c^2+13a^4b^3+20a^5bc-103a^4b^2c+95a^4c^2b+108a^3b^3c-180a^3b^2c^2)\geq0.$$

Also, by Rearrangement:
$$13\sum_{cyc}a^4b^3=13a^3b^3c^3\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{c^3}\geq13a^3b^3c^3\sum_{cyc}\left(a\cdot\frac{1}{a^3}\right)=13\sum_{cyc}a^3b^3c,$$
$$95\sum_{cyc}a^4c^2b=95a^2b^2c^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}\geq95a^2b^2c^2\sum_{cyc}a=95\sum_{cyc}a^3b^2c^2,$$
$$4\sum_{cyc}a^5c^2=4a^2b^2c^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{b^2}\geq4a^2b^2c^2\sum_{cyc}a=4\sum_{cyc}a^3b^2c^2,$$ by Muirhead $$81\sum_{cyc}a^3b^3c\geq81\sum_{cyc}a^3b^2c^2$$ and by the  Vasc's inequality $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a),$$ which gives
$$\sum_{cyc}(20a^5bc+40a^3b^3c)\geq60\sum_{cyc}a^4b^2c.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^6b+39a^5c^2-43a^4b^2c)\geq0$$ and since $$\sum_{cyc}a^6b\geq\sum_{cyc}a^4b^2c,$$
we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^6b+13a^5c^2-14a^4b^2c)\geq0.$$
Now, let $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $b=a+u,$ $c=a+v$.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}(a^6b+13a^5c^2-14a^4b^2c)=60(u^2-uv+v^2)a^5+$$
$$+2(47u^3-51u^2v+60uv^2+47v^3)a^4+$$
$$+(66u^4-92u^3v+46u^2v^2+204uv^3+66v^4)a^3+$$
$$+(19u^5-13u^4v-56u^3v^2+130u^2v^3+116uv^6+19v^5)a^2+$$
$$+(u^6+6u^5v-14u^4v^2+65u^2v^4+26uv^5+v^6)a+u^2v(u^4+13v^4)\geq0.$$

Comment: I don't think this is obvious as you commented in the question.

Comment: @Quang Hoang.- I agree with you however I add that "easy" is a word very relative in Maths and you know this very well.